# Center Typeform Popup Button in Squarespace

Tags: css, typeform

Embedding my Typeform on my Squarespace website Contact Page, as "Popup", not "Right Drawer" or "Left Drawer", but I cannot get it to center. It aligns to the left. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
<a class="typeform-share button" href="https://artisan82interiors.typeform.com/to/KAh3xu" data-mode="popup" style="display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;background-color:#267DDD;color:white;cursor:pointer;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:50px;text-align:center;margin:0;height:50px;padding:0px 33px;border-radius:25px;max-width:100%;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;font-weight:bold;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;"
  data-submit-close-delay="3" target="_blank">Launch me </a>
<script>
  (function() {
    var qs, js, q, s, d = document,
      gi = d.getElementById,
      ce = d.createElement,
      gt = d.getElementsByTagName,
      id = "typef_orm_share",
      b = "https://embed.typeform.com/";
    if (!gi.call(d, id)) {
      js = ce.call(d, "script");
      js.id = id;
      js.src = b + "embed.js";
      q = gt.call(d, "script")[0];
      q.parentNode.insertBefore(js, q)
    }
  })()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue, and found a workaround, so sharing it in case it helps you (or anyone else reading).

Embed the Typeform using a code block, and wrap the Typeform code in   like so:

```
<center> [Your Typeform code] </center>
```